# Efficient technique for selecting from a join table with a base item query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've got a pretty standard database setup with a parent-child relationship in it. Something like a parent table, a child table, and a parent_child_relationship table where a parent has many and belongs to many children (so not strictly parent-child).

What I want to do is, when writing SQL for my API, pull up a parent with a particular ID and then also grab the child IDs for all the children in the relationship.

I'm currently doing this in just two queries - `select * from parents where id = ?` and `select child_id as id from parent_child_relationship where parent_id = ?`.

What I'm curious about is: is there any particularly good way to do this all in one query? I experimented with stuff like array_agg in the form

```
select parents.*, array_agg(parent_child_relationship.child_id)
from parents join parent_child_relationship
  on parents.id = parent_child_relationship.parent_id
where parents.id = ?
group by parents.id, parents.otherfield, parents.yetanotherfield
```

but this is pretty inefficient (when I have a bunch of these relationships on parent), as you actually end up needing to do a distinct filter in there, and again: quite slow. The real-world query I tested with took like 5 minutes to complete.

I'm working through different versions with EXPLAIN to figure things out myself, but I thought this kind of need might be moderately common and there was a Best Way to do this.

I can always just keep doing one query for each relationship, too. This just felt like a place where I could simplify some stuff.

Comment: so the expected result is only row with stuffed child ids?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this version:

```
select p.*,
       (select array_agg(pc.child_id)
        from parent_child_relationship pcr
        where p.id = pcr.parent_id
       ) as children
from parents p
where p.id = ?;
```

I'm not sure why your version would be slow . . . unless you are missing an index.  Both versions want an index on `parent_child_relationship(parent_id, child_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

A very good blog about what you want - displaying one row with stuffed child ids
over array_to_string (array_agg() )

> While your original query does not have array_to_string this could be
>   the difference maker

http://www.craigkerstiens.com/2013/04/17/array-agg/

Example

```
 SELECT 
      users.email,
      array_to_string(array_agg(projects.name), ',')) as projects
    FROM
      projects,
      tasks,
      users
    WHERE projects.id = tasks.project_id
      AND tasks.due_at > tasks.completed_at
      AND tasks.due_at > now()
      AND users.id = projects.user_id
    GROUP BY 
      users.email
```